# When piping output to a file, why are stderr and stdout in the wrong order?

Tags: bash, perl, pipe, stdout

I have a perl script:

```
warn "1\n";
print "2\n";
warn "3\n";
print "4\n";
```

I pipe the output to a file:

```
perl script.pl &> foo
```

cat foo:

```
1
3
2
4
```

Why isn't the output in order, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STDERR is automatically flushed after printing a line, STDOUT is not. The STDOUT buffer is flushed only if it's full. To force autoflushing also on STDOUT use

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

(If you have an older perl, then the above may not work, instead you have to use something like `$| = 1;`)

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected if I autoflush both STDERR and STDOUT.